# Ubuntu 14.04LTS - Hotkeys don't work unless an application is open

Tags: unity, 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

This is a strange one for you all!

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS and I have Guake Terminal installed which has a hotkey to make it pop open on the screen when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>. This stopped working a few days ago.

But I initially thought it was a problem with Guake but now I find that no Hotkeys work unless I have any application open and running.

So, for example.

If I just have a blank desktop showing then when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> nothing happens, If I press any of my keyboard special keys which open a calculator or email application nothing happens. If I open up any application, e.g. Chrome / Libreoffice and then press <kbd>F12</kbd> - Guake opens, If I press the keyboard button for the calculator - it opens.

When I close the application, e.g. Chrome or Libreoffice, and try the hotkeys again - nothing happens.

What could be causing this?